# Memory leak after using calloc and free?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I tested my software with "valgrind --leak-check=full", and it shows:

```
==90862== 7,627 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 858 of 897
==90862==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==90862==    by 0xD64991C: concat(int, ...) (Client.cpp:150)
```

I can't understand why, because I use free() after calloc.
Here's my code:

```
char* p = concat(2, buffOld, buff);
char *x;
    while(true) {
        x = p;
        p = strstr(p,"\\final\\");
        if(p == NULL) { break; }
        *p = 0;
        p+=7;
        parseIncoming((char *)x,strlen(x));
    }
free(p);
```

And the "concat" function:

```
char* concat(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int i;

    // Find required length to store merged string
    int len = 1; // room for NULL
    va_start(ap, count);
    for(i=0 ; i<count ; i++)
        len += strlen(va_arg(ap, char*));
    va_end(ap);

    // Allocate memory to concat strings
    char *merged = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char),len);
    int null_pos = 0;

    // Actually concatenate strings
    va_start(ap, count);
    for(i=0 ; i<count ; i++)
    {
        char *s = va_arg(ap, char*);
        strcpy(merged+null_pos, s);
        null_pos += strlen(s);
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return merged;
}
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using `std::string`?

Comment: In your `while` you modify `p`.

Comment: At a glance it looks like you're moving the address the pointer `p` points to and therefore not freeing the memory allocated. And isn't this C code? Also the cast at `parseIncoming((char *)x,strlen(x));` seems redundant?

Comment: I'm modifying/improving a server for a Multiplayer Game ( https://github.com/Masaq-/Openspy-Core/blob/master/playerspy/Client.cpp ), and that's how it was made :) It wasn't using std::string. I could re-write it, but the whole code is very long, so it would require a lot of time to fix.
"parseIncoming((char *)x,strlen(x));" does some other stuff with game requests, so I don't feel like changing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't understand why, because I use free() after calloc

Yes, but (if I understand correctly) you `free()` the wrong pointer.

You should copy `p` in another pointer (before modifing it) and `free()` the save copy.

Look at your code

```
char* p = concat(2, buffOld, buff);
char *x;
    while(true) {
        x = p;
        p = strstr(p,"\\final\\");
        if(p == NULL) { break; }
        *p = 0;
        p+=7;
        parseIncoming((char *)x,strlen(x));
    }
free(p);
```

The pointer `p` is initialized with the calloc-ed pointer but the `while` cicle modify it and return only when `p` is `NULL`.

So, when you call

```
free(p)
```

you're calling

```
free(nullptr)
```

**--- EDIT ---**

> I still don't understand it. I added free(x) at the end, and it crashes

My initial suggestion to `free(x)` was a mistake of mine because I didn't pointed the attention to the fact that `x` is initializes with the `p` value but is modified in the `while` loop. Thanks again to Johnny Mopp for pointing my attention to it.

I suggest the use of another variable to memorize the original value of `p` (the exact value returned by `calloc()`) and free this value.

Something like

```
char* p = concat(2, buffOld, buff);
char *x;
char * const  forFree = p; /* <--- saving calloc() returned value */

while(true) {
    x = p;
    p = strstr(p,"\\final\\");
    if(p == NULL) { break; }
    *p = 0;
    p+=7;
    parseIncoming((char *)x,strlen(x));
}

free(forFree);
```

Comment: `x` gets modified, too.

Comment: @Mopp - D'oh! You're right; thanks! Modified my answer.

Comment: @Praetorian - thanks to you too; modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you, however I still don't understand it.
I added free(x) at the end, and it crashes:
==95965== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==95965==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
What do you mean by "copy p to another pointer"? What should I use for it? So "x = p;" doesn't copy the string to it?

Comment: @Mona - improved my answer; hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I finally understood it. So it's all about memory "addresses", and when the "while" loop was changing them, it was impossible to free the real callocated memory :)

Comment: @Mona - exactly; you must be sure to call `free()` passing it the exact **value** returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`